# Return row ID on button click using SQL and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, file-upload, delete-row

I'm creating an application that lets a user upload a file to the server. Once they have uploaded a site admin then has an admin page that is used to see all of the uploaded files, download the file, delete the file, and "mark" the file as read. I have the file upload feature working correctly as well as inserting information into the SQL database(filename, id, filepath, marked, and date). I also have the data being displayed correctly in a gridview with a "delete" and "read" buttons.

My problem is deleting an entry on click of the delete button. How would I best be able to pull the ID of the row so that I can successfully create a DELETE statement in SQL?

Some code:

admin.aspx

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="results" AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowcommand="results_BtnClick">
    <columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="filename" HeaderText="File Name"/>
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="filePath" Text="Download" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Delete" CommandName="del" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Read?" CommandName="Check"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="checked" HeaderText="Read Status?" />
    </columns>

    </asp:GridView>
```

admin.aspx.cs

```
protected void results_BtnClick(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {

                DbConn dbConn = new DbConn();
                //SQL = "SELECT * FROM databasename";
                //ds = new DataSet();
                //ds = dbConn.createDataSet(SQL);
                //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                //dt = ds.Tables[0];

                if (e.CommandName == "del")
                {
                    /* 
                     * Do Delete
                     */

                    SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection(dbConn.connStr);
                    SQL = "DELETE FROM databasename WHERE id=@id";
                    SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand();

                    oCmd = new SqlCommand(SQL);
                    oCmd.Connection = oConn;
                    oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4));
                    oCmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);




                    oConn.Open();

                    oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    oConn.Close();
                    sel_All(sender, e);
                }

                else if (e.CommandName == "Check")
                {
                    /* 
                     * Do Check Yes
                     */



                    SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection(dbConn.connStr);
                    SQL = "UPDATE databasename SET checked=@check WHERE id=@id";
                    SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand();

                    oCmd = new SqlCommand(SQL);
                    oCmd.Connection = oConn;
                    oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4));
                    oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@check", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
                    oCmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) + 1;
                    oCmd.Parameters["@check"].Value = "Yes";



                    oConn.Open();

                    oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    oConn.Close();
                    sel_All(sender, e);



                }
            }
```

I've searched around for ideas of how to do this, but my googlefu is quite weak. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Solution:

```
protected void results_BtnClick(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "del")
                {

                    int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                    int primaryID = Convert.ToInt32(results.DataKeys[id].Value);

                ....Do Delete....
                }
        }
```

I had many issues trying to use `Rows` `RowIndex` and the like. The method above works for me and gets around the issue of missing assemblies.

Hope this helps someone with similar issues!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to make the `ID` column a `TemplateField` with an ASP.NET `HiddenField` control inside of it to hold the ID value and then in the row command event handler you find the `HiddenField` control and pull the ID value out of it, like this:

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="results" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
              onrowcommand="results_BtnClick">
    <columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
            <asp:HiddenField id="HiddenFieldId" runat="server" 
                             Value='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="filename" HeaderText="File Name"/>
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="filePath" Text="Download" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Delete" CommandName="del" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Read?" CommandName="Check"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="checked" HeaderText="Read Status?" />
    </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void results_BtnClick(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{                
    if (e.CommandName == "del")
    {
        // Get the hidden field control from the current row
        var theHiddenField = e.Row.FindControl("HiddenFieldId") as HiddenField;

        // The as operator will return null for an unsuccessful cast
        // so check if we have something before we try to use it
        if(theHiddenField != null)
        {
            // Get the ID value
            var theId = Convert.ToInt32(theHiddenField.Value);

            // Do delete with ID value
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had problems getting the hidden field to actually work. I couldn't get things to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
int id=Convert.ToInt32( GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text);
```